# Image becomes white instead of Transparent in IE8

Tags: css, image, opacity

Opacity is not working in Ie8.. Image becomes white instead of transparent... 
But it works fine in chrome....

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=00);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
opacity: 0.0;
```

I'm using this... Please help me in Ie8

Comment: Why would you put `Opacity=50` and `-moz-opacity:0.5` if you want full transparent? I suspect you copied this code elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`filter: alpha(opacity=X);` is the filter for IE8 and earlier versions. if you set it to 00 value so you will not see anything in IE8 and earlier versions, if you want it to be 0.5 value so change it to `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`